# How to Autocomplete link in sublime text 2

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

Hey I have to link a file in my html like this:

And I'm trying real hard to autocomplete the file link, for eg: if I type this:
stylesheets/s
or something it should suggest me style.css or anything similar. How do I achieve that, in webstorm phpstorm I've encountered this autocomplete feature which allows me to browse the files and also assures me that the link I'm typing is correct, please let me know if there is a way to do that or should I revert back to some other IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you checkout the following package for Sublime:

https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AutoFileName